# How to ensure an endpoint is called twice?

Tags: rest, http

I have this endpoint that can delete potentially sensitive data.
The item to be deleted can have related items in different tables on the database.

If it doesn't, then we can proceed and delete the data.
But if it has, I'd like to implement a simple double-check feature, where the user would need to pass a parameter like `deleteDependencies=true`, which would allow to delete the related items.

I've considered generating a hash upon the first try and returning it in case of failure. Then the user would need to pass this hash on the second try.

But I'm not sure that's the best option.

Comment: 2 APIs might be more clear to others - like GetDeletePermission() => token then Delete( ..., token ) .  GetDeletePermisson can return a token (or empty string) and a failure/success code.  Failure might be a range of error codes.